# Perfect forwarding of variadic template templates

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, option-type, c++17, variadic-functions

I'm currently playing around with some of the new C++17 features, specifically `std::optional`, and I decided I'd have a go at coming up with a minimum-finding function using variadic template templates. This is what I have so far:

```cpp
template <template <typename> typename Opt, 
          typename T>
Opt<T> optional_min(Opt<T>&& opt) {
    return std::forward<Opt<T>>(opt);
}

template <template <typename> typename Opt0,
          template <typename> typename Opt1,
          template <typename> typename... Opts, typename T >
std::common_type_t<Opt0<T>, Opt1<T>, Opts<T>...> 
optional_min(Opt0<T>&& opt0, Opt1<T>&& opt1, Opts<T>&&... opts) {
    if (!opt0 && !opt1) 
    {
        return optional_min(std::optional<T>(std::nullopt), std::forward<Opts<T>>(opts)...);
    } 
    else if (opt0 && !opt1) 
    {
        return optional_min(opt0, std::forward<Opts<T>>(opts)...);
    } 
    else if (!opt0 && opt1) 
    {
        return optional_min(opt1, std::forward<Opts<T>>(opts)...);
    } 
    else 
    {
        return (*opt0 < *opt1) ? 
            optional_min(opt0, std::forward<Opts<T>>(opts)...) 
                : optional_min(opt1, std::forward<Opts<T>>(opts)...);
    }
}

int main() {
    std::optional<int> a = 9;
    std::optional<int> b = std::nullopt;
    std::optional<int> c = 4;

    if (auto x = optional_min(a, b, c)) 
        std::cout << *x << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It seems like my forwarding isn't working. I'm still new to the idea of forwarding, so I could just be missing something silly. The error I get is this:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'optional_min(std::optional<int>&, std::optional<int>&, std::optional<int>&)'

error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type 'std::optional<int>&' to lvalue of type 'std::optional<int>'
  auto x = optional_min(a, b, c);
```

My compiler is also telling me that my variadic `optional_min` function is only a close match, and that it's trying to match my other `optional_min` function, that one that only takes in one argument. Does anyone know why this might be the case? Please let me know if you need to know a little more.

Comment: Forwarding reference is the one like `T&&`. `Op<T>` already dictates the value category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of `optional_min`'s parameters are forwarding references.  They are all rvalue references.

Forwarding references are formed when you declare a parameter to be an rvalue reference to a deduced template type parameter, but that's not the case here.  `optional_min`'s parameters are rvalue references to instantiations of deduced template *template* parameters.

To avoid this, just get rid of the `Opt0`, `Opt1` and `Opts` template template parameters, and use type parameters directly:

```
template <typename Opt0, typename Opt1, typename... Opts>
auto optional_min(Opt0&& opt0, Opt1&& opt1, Opts&&... opts) {
    //...
}
```

You could use SFINAE to limit the type parameters to instantiations of `std::optional` if that's your goal.

Comment: Thank you! This was extremely helpful.

Comment: Actually, I have a question... If the function is given an rvalue parameter, how would it end up returning a reference to the object?

Comment: I removed that bit.  You're returning by value, so I was just plain wrong.